# How to get EventPattern working in Nest JS

Tags: nestjs

I am setting up basic EventPattern between two NestJS instances. However the Event is not being emitted/received  by the other Microservice.

I have tried to find some concrete examples on the docs, however it looks the setup is different than calling clinet.emit/client.call to invoke other microservices.

Microservice 1.

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Client, Transport, ClientProxy, ClientsModule, EventPattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Client({ transport: Transport.REDIS })
  client: ClientProxy;

  @Get()
  async call(): Promise<number> {
    const pattern = { cmd: 'sum' };
    const payload = [1, 2, 3];
    const result = await this.client.emit('user_created', {age: 5});
    return this.client.send<number>(pattern, payload).toPromise();
  }


}
```

Microservice two

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern, EventPattern, Client, Transport, ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Controller()
export class MathController {

  @Client({ transport: Transport.REDIS })
  client: ClientProxy;

  @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'sum' })
  sum(data: number[]): number {
    console.log('Message');
    return 1;
  }

  @EventPattern('user_created')
  async handleUserCreated(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
    console.log('EVENT');
    // business logic
  }
}
```

When we call `Microservice1.get` the client the call to `sum` does occur and `Message` is printed on `Microservice 2`. 
However the expectation is that `EVENT` is printed on `Microservice 2` too.

Comment: Can you try setting the `port` for the `client` explicitly?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue while testing the framework and I was able to get the expected outcome by adding `toPromise()` on the `emit` call.

So you can try:

`const result = await this.client.emit('user_created', {age: 5});.toPromise()`

`emit` returns an observable so you have to subscribe to it. Either `toPromise()` or `subscribe()` will do.

For more information: https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/rxjs-primer.html